# Downloader Thread Dispatcher Causes Program to Hang

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I'm using Visual Studio 2015, WPF, C#.

This is example code to a larger project that replicates the Error.

Test Project source here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xtlpfhecm1mfv5m/Downloader.zip?dl=0

---

I have a ComboBox where you choose a File Download.

In the example it downloads the StackOverflow logo png from imgur to Downloads folder.

[image: Downloader Program]

---

#### Problem

ComboBox SelectedItem Error

```
if ((string)cboDownload.SelectedItem == "File 1") { ... }
```

`The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.`

I add a `Dispatcher` inside the `Thread`.

**But the Dispatcher causes the program to freeze when you press the Download button.**

---

#### Solutions

I can only get it to work if I set the `ComboBox` `Selected Item` to a `string` before the Thread:

```
string cboDownloadItem = cboDownload.SelectedItem.ToString();

if ((string)cboDownloadItem == "File 1") { ... }
```

But I'd rather not have to do that.

---

#### XAML

```
<Label x:Name="labelProgressInfo" 
       Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
       Margin="10,55,10,0" 
       VerticalAlignment="Top" 
       Width="497"/>

<ProgressBar x:Name="progressBar" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
             Height="24" Margin="10,89,0,0"
             VerticalAlignment="Top" 
             Width="487"/>

<ComboBox x:Name="cboDownload" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Margin="122,171,0,0" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Width="120" 
          SelectedIndex="0">
    <System:String>File 1</System:String>
    <System:String>File 2</System:String>
</ComboBox>

<Button x:Name="btnDownload"
        Content="Download" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Margin="278,173,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="75"
        Click="btnDownload_Click"/>
```

#### Strings

```
string fileBaseUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/";
string fileName = string.Empty;
string localPath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%USERPROFILE%") + "\\Downloads\\";
```

#### Download Button

```
private void btnDownload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Start New Thread
    //
    Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            // ComboBox Selected Download
            //
            if ((string)cboDownload.SelectedItem == "File 1")
            {
                // StackOverflow Logo
                fileName = "WTminjY.png";
            }

            waiter = new ManualResetEvent(false);

            Uri downloadUrl = new Uri(fileBaseUrl + fileName);
            wc.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(wc_DownloadProgressChanged);
            wc.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadFileCompleted);
            wc.DownloadFileAsync(downloadUrl, localPath + fileName);

            // Progress TextBox
            progressInfo = "Downloading...";

            // Wait for Download to complete
            waiter.WaitOne();

            // Progress TextBox
            progressInfo = "Download Complete";
        });
    });


    // Start Download Thread
    //
    thread.Start();
}
```

#### Download Handlers

```
public void wc_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Progress TextBox
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        labelProgressInfo.Content = progressInfo;
    });

    // Progress Bar
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        double bytesIn = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
        double totalBytes = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
        double percentage = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100;
        progressBar.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());
    });
}


public void wc_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    waiter.Set();

    // Progress TextBox
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        labelProgressInfo.Content = progressInfo;
    });
}
```

Comment: "I add a Dispatcher inside the Thread", what exactly does that mean? Did you call `cboBoxDownload.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...)`?

Comment: Can't you just download the file on the new thread completely? Without invoking it?

Comment: @Clemens I used `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate`. I tried `cboDownload.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>` but it still freezes.

Comment: @IanH. If I don't invoke it, the Thread can't access the `(string)cboDownload.SelectedItem`. It gives `The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.`

Comment: Also, correcting a typo. `cboBoxDownload` is supposed to be `cboDownload`.